# Uncaught TypeError when trying to alter image states

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a piece of code that when a button is clicked, it checks through a list of images, checks if it has an id of 'video' and if it does then display an overlay and remove the player that is there.

I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Here is the code:

```
$("#actions .btn").click(function(){
       $('.span img').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('video') != -1){
                var spanid = $(this).attr('id').replace(/video/, '');
                $(this).removeClass('hideicon');
                $('#mediaplayer' + spanid + '_wrapper').remove();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method will return `undefined` if the attribute you're looking for doesn't exist on the element. I would suggest adding an extra check to your condition:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
if(id && id.indexOf('video') != -1) {
    //OK!
}
```

From the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method returns `undefined` for attributes that have not been set.

Interestingly, the native `getAttribute` function returns `null` for attributes that haven't been set. jQuery, for some reason, [explicity checks for this](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.attr) and returns `undefined` instead:

```
ret = elem.getAttribute(name);

// Non-existent attributes return null, we normalize to undefined
return ret === null ? undefined : ret;
```

Comment: Ahh good shout. I added the extra check and the functionality works now. It was also partially a scope issue. Mistake on my part. Thanks for the help!